# Can you remove the alpha channel in a PNG with SIPS?

Tags: macos, terminal, png, transparency, sips

Trying to stay *native* in SIPS when removing the alpha channel from images I am familiar with the process in ImageMagick with:

```
convert -flatten test.png test-white.png
```

or:

```
convert test.png -background white -alpha remove test.png
```

but when I reference the man page on [ss4](http://ss64.com/osx/sips.html) and [Library](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) it tells me that `hasAlpa` is a boolean read only when I run:

```
sips -g hasAlpha test.png
```

Per searching under the tag [sips](/questions/tagged/sips) and with:

- [sips transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsips%5D%20transparency)
- [sips remove](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsips%5D%20remove)

there wasn't anything mentioned for removing transparency.  Can you remove transparency with SIPS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ImageMagick or GraphicsMagick would be better idea, but if you *really* want to use SIPS, you could try to remove transparency by converting image to BMP, and then back to PNG again:

```
sips -s format bmp input.png --out tmp.bmp
sips -s format png tmp.bmp --out output.png
```

Unfortunately you cannot choose background color, transparent parts of image will be replaced with black.

Comment: This is useful if you have a single pixel on which the alpha is wrong that you need to fix.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following little script, which uses OSX's built-in **PHP** which includes **GD** by default, so you would be staying *native* and not need **ImageMagick** or anything extra installed:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f

<?php
// Get start image with transparency
$src = imagecreatefrompng('start.png');

// Get width and height
$w = imagesx($src);
$h = imagesy($src);

// Make a blue canvas, same size, to overlay onto
$result = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
$blue = imagecolorallocate($result,0,0,255);
imagefill($result,0,0,$blue);

// Overlay start image ontop of canvas
imagecopyresampled($result,$src,0,0,0,0,$w,$h,$w,$h);

// Save result
imagepng($result,'result.png',0);
?>
```

So, if I start with this, which is transparent in the middle:

[image]

I get this as a result:

[image]

I made the canvas background blue so you can see it on StackOverflow's white background, but just change lines 12 & 13 for a white background like this:

```
...
...
// Make a white canvas, same size, to overlay onto
$result = imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
$white = imagecolorallocate($result,255,255,255);
imagefill($result,0,0,$white);
...
...
```

I did another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35128743/2836621) in the same vein to overcome another missing feature in `sips`.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which is much lighter weight than installing the entire **ImageMagick** might be to use the **NetPBM** suite:

```
pngtopam -background=rgb:ff/ff/ff -mix start.png | pnmtopng - > result.png
```

You can easily install **NetPBM** using `homebrew` with:

```
brew install netpbm
```