# Use ImageMagick in Cocoa/OSX application

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, imagemagick

I've been trying to find a solution to this for a long time, but I still cannot figure out how to do this.

### What I need

To be able to execute a `convert` command (or equivalent in code) from within an OSX app, regardless of whether the user has ImageMagick (and its dependencies) installed.

### What I've tried

Given that we have to cover (obviously) the case where the user doesn't already have ImageMagick installed, I assume we have to make it somehow self-contained...

**Approach A** : *Pack the binary, plain and simple, within the bundle, and execute it with `NSTask`.*

Working? Yes, but only on my Mac where every library is pre-installed.

**Approach B** : *Link with the static libraries.*

This is the more... obvious approach. However, there are still issues.

I first tried using these [precompiled IM release + Delegates](https://github.com/marforic/imagemagick_lib_iphone). After a lot of tweaks, I got it to work.

The thing is: it include the JPEG, PNG, TIFF delegates. But not the FreeType one which I definitely need.

So... I tried re-compiling it all from scratch AND the FreeType delegate. And here come all sorts of issues (all mostly related with libraries being missing). I mean... I link the static libraries, then see a complete list of errors... add some missing library... and then a new list of errors appear. Obviously, something is wrong.

Here's what it looks like :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FcConfigDestroy", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcFontList", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcFontSetDestroy", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcInitLoadConfigAndFonts", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcObjectSetBuild", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcObjectSetDestroy", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcPatternCreate", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcPatternDestroy", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcPatternGetInteger", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_FcPatternGetString", referenced from:
      _LoadFontConfigFonts in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-type.o)
  "_ImfCloseInputFile", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfCloseOutputFile", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfDeleteHeader", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfErrorMessage", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfFloatToHalf", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfHalfToFloat", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfHeaderDataWindow", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfHeaderDisplayWindow", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfHeaderSetCompression", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfHeaderSetDataWindow", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfHeaderSetDisplayWindow", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfHeaderSetLineOrder", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfInputHeader", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfInputReadPixels", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfInputSetFrameBuffer", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfNewHeader", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfOpenInputFile", referenced from:
      _ReadEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfOpenOutputFile", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfOutputSetFrameBuffer", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_ImfOutputWritePixels", referenced from:
      _WriteEXRImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-exr.o)
  "_cmsCloseProfile", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
      _GetImageProperty in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-property.o)
      _GetMagickProperty in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-property.o)
  "_cmsCreateTransformTHR", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_cmsDeleteTransform", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_cmsDoTransform", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_cmsGetColorSpace", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_cmsGetDeviceClass", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_cmsGetPCS", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_cmsGetProfileInfoASCII", referenced from:
      _GetImageProperty in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-property.o)
      _GetMagickProperty in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-property.o)
  "_cmsOpenProfileFromMem", referenced from:
      _GetImageProperty in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-property.o)
      _GetMagickProperty in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-property.o)
  "_cmsOpenProfileFromMemTHR", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_cmsSetLogErrorHandler", referenced from:
      _ProfileImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-profile.o)
  "_ddjvu_cache_set_size", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_context_create", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_context_release", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_document_create", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_document_get_pageinfo_imp", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_document_get_pagenum", referenced from:
      _process_message in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_document_job", referenced from:
      _process_message in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_format_create", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_format_release", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_format_set_row_order", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_format_set_y_direction", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_job_get_user_data", referenced from:
      _process_message in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_job_release", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_job_set_user_data", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_job_status", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_message_peek", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
      _pump_data_until_message in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_message_pop", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_message_wait", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_page_create_by_pageno", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_page_get_type", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_page_job", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_page_render", referenced from:
      _ReadDJVUImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_stream_close", referenced from:
      _pump_data_until_message in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_ddjvu_stream_write", referenced from:
      _pump_data_until_message in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-djvu.o)
  "_fftw_cleanup", referenced from:
      _ForwardFourierTransformImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
      _InverseFourierTransformImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
  "_fftw_destroy_plan", referenced from:
      _ForwardFourierTransformChannel in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
      _InverseFourierTransformChannel in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
  "_fftw_execute_dft_c2r", referenced from:
      _InverseFourierTransformChannel in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
  "_fftw_execute_dft_r2c", referenced from:
      _ForwardFourierTransformChannel in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
  "_fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d", referenced from:
      _InverseFourierTransformChannel in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
  "_fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d", referenced from:
      _ForwardFourierTransformChannel in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-fourier.o)
  "_lzma_auto_decoder", referenced from:
      _ReadMIFFImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-miff.o)
  "_lzma_code", referenced from:
      _ReadMIFFImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-miff.o)
      _WriteMIFFImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-miff.o)
  "_lzma_easy_encoder", referenced from:
      _WriteMIFFImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-miff.o)
  "_lzma_end", referenced from:
      _ReadMIFFImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-miff.o)
      _WriteMIFFImage in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-miff.o)
  "_opj_create_compress", referenced from:
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_create_decompress", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_decode", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_destroy_codec", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_destroy_cstr_index", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_encode", referenced from:
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_end_compress", referenced from:
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_end_decompress", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_get_decoded_tile", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_image_create", referenced from:
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_image_destroy", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_read_header", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_set_decode_area", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_set_default_decoder_parameters", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_set_default_encoder_parameters", referenced from:
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_set_error_handler", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_set_warning_handler", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_setup_decoder", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_setup_encoder", referenced from:
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_start_compress", referenced from:
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_create", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_destroy", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_set_read_function", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_set_seek_function", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_set_skip_function", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_set_user_data", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_set_user_data_length", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_stream_set_write_function", referenced from:
      _ReadJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
      _WriteJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
  "_opj_version", referenced from:
      _RegisterJP2Image in libMagickCore-6.Q8.a(magick_libMagickCore_6_Q8_la-jp2.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

---

Any suggestions? Have you managed to use ImageMagick from Cocoa at all?

Comment: Off topic, but what are you doing with `convert`? In the world of Cocoa, you already have CoreImageFilters & CoreGraphics that handle the majority of features offered by IM.

Comment: @emcconville Watermarking images (including but not limited to text).

Comment: If you just want to do relatively simple things like watermarking, resizing and compositing, you could use the `GD` functions in the built-in `PHP` interpreter... `/usr/bin/php -i | grep -A20 gd` and draw text with TrueType fonts http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39272442/2836621 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/35128743/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Awesome suggestion - I'll definitely give it a try! (And imagine I'm a PHP guy...) Thanks a lot! :)